# Too hard to imagine

Tags: grammar, word-order

I have written an answer to this question below.
"Would you kill animals for fun or sport?"

My answer is "It's too hard to imagine for me." But I think it's wrong so I  changed it into "For me, it's too hard to imagine that." Is it correct?
Can I also use "for me" at the end of the corrected sentence? I don't like it, though.
As in "It's too hard to imagine that for me."

Comment: I don't think yours is really a suitable context for saying what you can or can't imagine. You're just being asked whether you'd do something for fun. If you can't imagine doing it at all, presumably you ***wouldn't*** do it for fun. But suppose you were asked ***Would you enjoy being rich if you won the lottery**?* Saying ***I can't imagine winning the lottery**!* certainly wouldn't mean you wouldn't enjoy being rich, so why should saying you can't imagine killing animals automatically imply you wouldn't enjoy doing it?

Comment: If I can't even imagine doing it, for me it means I will never do it.

Comment: There's always going to be confusion between *I can't imagine **doing** it* and *I can't imagine **enjoying** doing it.* I'm sure there have been plenty of people who couldn't imagine having sex - but when they actually *did*, they enjoyed it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's too hard to imagine for me
- It's too hard to imagine that for me

These are both awkward.  You could say:

- It's too hard for me to imagine that.

However, it would be better to say:

- It's too hard for me to imagine doing that.

I think "extremely hard" or "impossible" would sound better though:

- It's impossible for me to imagine doing that.
- It's impossible for me to imagine myself doing that.
- For me, it's impossible to imagine doing that.

You could also say:

- I can't imagine doing such a thing.
- I could never do such a thing.
- I could never do that.
- I would never do such a thing.
- I would never do that.

Comment: Thank you do much. Even "For me, it's too hard to imagine that" doesn't work.